# Text in Ellipses JavaFX

Tags: text, javafx, ellipse

I created a custom venn chart for two sets an their intersection in JavaFX.

Now I want to show the number of elements in this sets like in the following picture:

[image]

The sets are ellipses and I used masks to give the intersection a different color.

Now I want to show the number with size and position related to the available space so that the numbers are always inside the according area.
The width for the text element is easy to calculate, but I don't know how to get available height for the text elements.

Maybe it could be helpful to have the pixels of the ellipses as path, but I have no idea to how I can get this.

Does anyone know how to implement that?

Edit:

I developed an algorithm to find the size of a rectangle, which fits in the required areas of the ellipses. The text are scaled to the size of the rectangle and it works, but now I have another problem.

I need to center the scaled text in the rectangle an I used a StackPane for that. But I can't position the StackPane in the chart parent. If I set the layoutX and layoutY the bounds in parent are different.

For example: stackPane with text = sp;

sp.setLayoutY(122.1662320906945);

The Result for getBoundsInParent().getMinY() is 97.16622924804688;

How can I set the StackPane position, if I use it in a chart class as chart children?